# Is a finitely generated module over a Hopfian ring Hopfian?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, hopfian

An $R$-module $M$ is called Hopfian if  every $R$-epimorphism ‎$‎f :M‎\longrightarrow ‎M$‎ is an automorphism.

Suppose that $R$ is a Hopfian ring and $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Is $M$ Hopfian?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you haven't defined "Hopfian ring". Do you mean that $R_R$ is hopfian as a module? The alternative would be for $R$ to be Hopfian *as a ring* that is, every *ring* surjection $R\to R$ is injective,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by "Hopfian ring" you mean that $R_R$ is a hopfian module. (But if you meant "Hopfian as a ring" I will need to delete this.)

What you have called a Hopfian ring is more commonly called a **Dedekind finite ring** or **directly finite ring**.

The answer is no: There exists a ring $R$ and an integer $n$ such that $R$ is Dedekind finite, and yet $M_n(R)$ is not Dedekind finite. Since $M_n(R)\cong End(R^n_R)$, you see this means that there is a surjective $R$-linear map from $R^n\to R^n$ that isn't injective.

Comment: Yes. I meant that R is Hopfian when  $R_R$ is Hopfian module.  Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @M.Ramana [Here](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/35/) is a description of such a ring.

Comment: \@rschwieb  Thank you so much for the link and your interesting counter example.

Comment: @M.Ramana Glad to have helped.

Comment: @M.Ramana I became curious and asked [the natural follow-up](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2454609/29335) to this question.

Comment: Thank you for your favor. It's my pleasure that my question  made you curious.

Comment: Thank you so much for the new link.

Comment: Excuse me. As you answered above, a finitely generated module over a Hopfian ring is not Hopfian in general. Could you help me about this question: is a finitely generated module over integral group ring of a free group Hopfian? I just know that by the Bass Theorem every finitely generated projective module over integral group ring of a free group is free.

Comment: @M.Ramana No, I have no idea.