# For what rings are all finitely generated right $R$ modules Hopfian?

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2454413/29335) a user wondered if all finitely generated modules over a Dedekind finite ring (a ring satisfying $xy=1\implies yx=1$ for all $x,y$) are Hopfian (every surjective homomorphism $M\to M$ is injective.)

As pointed out in the question, it is possible that there exists an $n$ such that $R^n$ is not Hopfian, so there are in fact counterexamples.

So at this point, we see it is necessary for $R$ to be **stably finite** (that is, all of its matrix rings are Dedekind finite.)

> Is stable finiteness sufficient to make all finitely generated $R$ modules Hopfian? Or is it perhaps equivalent to a stronger condition on $R$?

I suspect the answer is known, but I didn't spot an argument in the short while I've been thinking about it.

It's pretty obvious that $R$ being right Noetherian is sufficient, and this condition is strictly stronger than being stably finite. Another sufficient condition is having **stable range 1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is no. Let $k$ be a field and let $R = k\langle x, y \rangle$ be the free $k$-algebra on the non-commuting generators $x$ and $y$. Then $R$ is stably finite by Corollary 1.11 of Lam's book *Lectures on Modules and Rings* (the idea is to use Cohn's theorem that $R$ is a [free ideal ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_ideal_ring) and therefore embeds into a division ring, which is obviously stably finite). However, the ring $S = R/\langle xy - 1 \rangle$ is non-Hopfian as an $R$-module.

Comment: Just making sure: the point is that $S$ isn't Hopfian because left multiplication by $x$ induces a surjective right $R$ module homomorphism that has $yx-1 + I$ in its kernel, so it isn't injective... yes? This is a nice answer

Comment: Yes that's exactly right